# Deadlock on CRT locale critical section

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, windbg, msvcrt

**Discussing application bug:**

Rarely most application threads stuck on identically repeated deadlock. Deadlock reproduced about once a month on Windows XP and latter.

**Essential about our large project:**

Project builded as release target when bug was reproduced at customers machines.

Application compiled with /EHa consequently catch block with ellipsis (...) could sometimes hide access violations and other system exceptions.
(Please, don't discuss good or bad practise catch block with ellipsis).

Project consist of pure, pure CLR and mixed CLR assemblies (C++;C#;C++\CLI).

MSVS 2013

Most application threads use thread local C locale mode.

[WinDbg dump info, most essential](http://pastebin.com/FsYvAafV)

[WinDbg dump info, full stack traces](http://pastebin.com/aASJE7NB)

[Full dump (70Mb)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3jDtpEHildYbndoODRKa09IRTg/view?usp=sharing)

Most threads waiting on CRT locale critical section ("_mlock(_SETLOCALE_LOCK)" code on CRT sources), e.g. thread with WinDbg_ID=44.

Other threads waiting on loader critical section, e.g. thread with WinDbg_ID=23.

Probably 23 thread entered internally at CRT sources to CRT locale critical section and didn't left it.

44 thread enter to loader critical section before _CRTDLL_INIT/dllmain and waiting for crt-locale critical section at _CRTDLL_INIT/dllmain while execute DLL_THREAD_ATTACH.

dllmain is default generated.

Locale critical section was must left, because _munlock(_SETLOCALE_LOCK) should be at __finally block at CRT sources.

Probably occurred some system exception after enter at CRT locale critical section and when _munlock wasn't left CRT locale critical section.

Sort of unusual: 3 modules at process:

- msvcr80.dll - loaded by sqlncli10.dll
- msvcr120.dll
- msvcr120_clr0400.dll

**Questions:**

Is anyone have some ideas or explanations?

Is it possible to call from single thread a CRT locale functions from a different CRT versions? That probably corrupt the thread local CRT locale data memory because of a CRT difference. And some system exception was occurred after enter to the CRT locale critical section. Is it real?

Is it possible to skip __finally block? Skipping scenario?

Comment: Do you have some code using `CreateThread()`? You should replace it with `_beginthreadex()` (or something like that, please refer to the documentation). Concerning the three MSVCR libraries, check the dependency tree using "dependency walker" to find if they are directly used by the same module. If so, that's surely wrong, if not, it could still be wrong but doesn't have to.

Comment: There are a *large* number of deadlocks present, of all kind of variety and not just locale.  Looks like a bomb went off.   You can't get help with it here.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Our code doesn't use CreateThread. std::thread and pplx::task mostly.

Comment: @HansPassant Here is only one simple explanation of deadlock: The CRT locale critical section doesn't left, when should.

Answer (score 3):

Probably we found answer and will test this in practice.

We run backtrace logger on every not c++ exceptions in vectored exception handler and capture stack trace when it happens. Access violation after lock locale CS.

We used third party library ZipArchive into our project in multithread manner. In this library functions in deep of CZipString::MakeLower\CZipString::MakeUpper make local static variable std::locale and this is UB at C++98/MsVs 2013 in multithread case. It rarely just destroy top of stack and call to random code in code section without stack unwind correctly and without leave locale CS. Than access violation occur and state of thread "restored" by /EHa and catch(...). Than thread stuck at another CS after uncorrect stack unwinding.

Thanks all.